# Is the use of "at" and " to " according to the meaning of the sentence or are there general rules to be used?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Should I say:

> *Iam going to the school*

Or

> *Iam going at the school*

Comment: First, "I am" is two separate words. Second, when talking about attending a school for classes, you usually omit the definite article and use the preposition **to**: "I am going to school."  The sentence "I am going to the school," has the implication that you're going to the school building for some purpose other than as a student or teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say "I am going **to** the school"

"To" implies you are actually moving toward the school, but "at" is usually used for an action performed at a location one was already at, like

"I ate my lunch **at** the school"